# alfresco categories tree recursively

Tags: recursion, tree, alfresco, categories

I want to get all categories in alfresco. What i want to do is a function that return a tree  of all categories in the repository (may be recursively) and display it in category managment page.

I'd like to display the tree expanded by default (using Yahoo javascript library)

Thank you in advance.

I'm using alfresco 5.0.d

Comment: Isn't this what the existing category management page show you?{host}/share/page/console/admin-console/category-manager

Comment: yes but i want to list all categories without any clic.

Answer (score 0):

You ll want to change the category manager page. 
The code for the category manager (front end javascript, Yahoo js library) is in

> alfresco\tomcat\webapps\share\components\console\category-manager.js

Css styling  is in same dir

The back end webscript that provides the data is in

> alfresco\tomcat\webapps\share\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\site-webscripts\org\alfresco\components\console\category-manager.get.js

The freemarker template providing html can be found in the same directory.

Comment: I know ! but what i want to do is a function GetAllCategories() that return  all  categories from repository. I call GetAllCategories in  alfresco\tomcat\webapps\share\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\site-webscripts\org\alfresco\components\console\category-manager.get.js and will display all of them (with Yahoo dom library). 

My question is  how to do GetAllCategories()   ??

Comment: You re right, I can t find that webscript either. But I think it would be rather easy in adding a webscript that does that for you.  use lucene search like this: var nodes = search.luceneSearch("PATH:\"/cm:generalclassifiable//*");
   model.resultset = nodes; This javascript code will find all existing categories and make them available to return in ftl.